# Random category/word (FEATURES) as last category on the front end

Tags: category

```
Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
Amasty extensions
Webkul multi-step checkout
```

I have done some work with categories (moving them around, deleting some) on a site I'm developing and I noticed there is an extra category on the front end called FEATURES. This is NOT a category that would exist in Catalog -> Categories. I also checked:

- Content -> Pages - the home page

and nowhere in the home page file does it have the word FEATURES.

**How could I find out where this is coming from?**